# Getting Co-ordinates of a particular location using Bing Map api in python/odoo

Tags: python, bing-api, odoo-9

I have been working on a task in Odoo9 for getting latitude longitude using bing map api.In Odoo 9 there is a model called base_geolocalize where they used this function for getting lat/long by the help of google api

```
def find(addr):

url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAL-rowwysUmteIHcOXac86AbPiTV1j2zw&address='


try:
    result = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
except Exception, e:
    raise UserError(_(
        'Cannot contact geolocation servers. Please make sure that your internet connection is up and running (%s).') % e)
if result['status'] != 'OK':
    _logger.info('GEOLOCATION: status not OK' + str(result))
    return None

try:
    geo = result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
    return float(geo['lat']), float(geo['lng'])
except (KeyError, ValueError):
    return None
```

My question is that :- Can I get the same result using bing map and how.Please Help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Bing Maps REST services: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx

The structure of the response will be different from Google of course, but it will have the information you are looking for. Here is the structure of the response: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701725.aspx